# Getting 'no package' error when trying to import bigmemory package into R

Tags: r, import, r-bigmemory

I'm trying to import the bigmemory package into R. I downloaded the package from CRAN and saved it in the R package library on my local machine. In R I typed the library command to import the package:

```
> library(bigmemory)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Loading required package: bigmemory.sri
Error: package ‘bigmemory.sri’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :
  there is no package called ‘bigmemory.sri’
```

I've loaded other packages with no problem and am not sure why I'd get an error at this point. I haven't found anyone else that seems to have had this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `install.packages('bigmemory.sri')`

Comment: You said "I downloaded the package from can and saved it in the R package library.." this is not the right way to do it. Just use `install.packages` function as pointed out by @TylerRinker since it can handle dependencies and save you from this kind trouble. So a simple `install.packages("bigmemory")` will do a clean install

Comment: Actually it is fine way to do it, as long as you look up the dependencies, and install them first, and also use `repos=NULL` and the proper `type=` argument to match the file that was downloaded, and have the right system tools if it is a source package.

Comment: @DWin True but I'm guessing that's where the problems are occurring.